# How to Increment an int every day using a service in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a project that needs to keep track of how many days it has been since an object has been created. I have a SQLite database which has a column for this, but I do not know how to increment this column. How do I create a Service to increment this database column by one at some fixed time everyday?

Comment: Why not store the creation timestamp in the database and calculate the number of days based on this datum?

Comment: Could you not just store a created date, then as you need to, calculate the days passed since creation?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store a timestamp in the database indicating the creation time? Then you can compare to that as needed.

Comment: would that timestamp be for the database or for the row in the table?

Comment: You can write the current time to it however you need. Or you could configure it to automatically have the current timestamp when the row is created.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach. Store a simple integer in Shared Preferences, which represents the days since Epoch. Simply check if the `Current Date - Epoch` is bigger than that stored in Shared Preferences. If so, run your code, and replace the integer.